# Is the Xbox One power cable backward compatible with the original Xbox?

Tags: xbox-one, backwards-compatibility, xbox

I am looking to play some vintage games on the original Xbox but the power cord is missing. Is the power cord for the Xbox One backwards compatible with the original Xbox?

Answer (score 2):

The original Xbox used an [IEC 60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) type power cord and plugged directly into an outlet. I believe it specifically used the C7 variant. I've deduced this by looking at an image I found of the back of an original Xbox on eBay where the cord would plug in:

[image: original xbox power cord connection]

The *Xbox One* (the first model) uses a dedicated power supply that I believe is proprietary.  The part that connects to the console is similar in shape, but is much thicker, and would be impossible to plug into an original Xbox.

[image: example xbox one power supply]

Even if you could plug this into original Xbox, the Xbox One power supply is probably not rated the same as what the original Xbox required.

**Update**:

I did some more research into the later models of the Xbox One.

The *Xbox One S* and *Xbox One X* appears to use the same style cord, looking at the back of the console:

[image: xbox one x back of console]

<sub>[Image Source](https://support.xbox.com/en-IE/help/hardware-network/console/get-to-know-xbox-console)</sub>

If you have this cord, I would first try to plug it in to the original Xbox **without** the cord being powered.  If it fits nicely, then you should be fine, as this kind of power cord is fairly standard and doesn't make a difference in terms of the power delivery.

Thus, if you have an **Xbox one S or X power cord**, you should be able to use it. If you have the first model *Xbox One* power cord/supply, that won't work.